# Remove contents of <img></img> tag

Tags: c, string, getline

I have this code. The purpose of the code is to print everything before `<img>` and everything after `</img>`. Everything in between `<img>` and `</img>` should not be printed. However, I am having 2 issues.

1. The code is compiling on windows (gcc compiler) but when I run it, it just say's "program stopped working"?
2. The code is printing everything. It is even printing the `<img>`,
   `</img>` and     everything in between.

My #includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Code:

```
void replacer_and_print(FILE *fp) {

char* line;
size_t len;
ssize_t read;

bool found_tag = false;
int line_storer;
char* before_tag;
char* after_tag;

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if (
        ((before_tag = strstr(line, "<img>")) != NULL) &&
        ((after_tag = strstr(line, "</img>")) != NULL)
       ) {   
        line_storer = before_tag - line; 
        printf("%.*s", line_storer, line);

        printf("The Image use to be here\n");
        line_storer = after_tag - line + strlen("</img>"); 
        printf("%s", line + line_storer);

    } else if ((before_tag = strstr(line, "<img>")) != NULL) {
        line_storer = before_tag - line; 
        printf("%.*s", line_storer, line);

        found_tag = true;

    } else if((after_tag = strstr(line, "</img>")) != NULL) {
        found_tag = false;

        line_storer = after_tag - line + strlen("</img>"); 
        printf("%s", line + line_storer);

    } else if(!found_tag) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}

fclose(fp);
}
```

---

test.html:

```
<b>This is a test page</b>
<div class=back1>Some more text here for more testing!!!!</div>
<img>www.website.com/image.png</img>
<i>More words</i>
<u><i><b>TESTING 123</u></i></b>
```

---

output:

```
<b>This is a test page</b>
<div class=back1>Some more text here for more testing!!!!</div>
The Image use to be here
<i>More words</i>
<u><i><b>TESTING 123</u></i></b>
```

---

Assumptions:

```
There will only be one <img>
There will only be one </img>. The </img> tag will always be after the <img>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  For the most part, this is a good first post; however, you should include any errors you won't help with in your post.  You state that the code won't compile on Windows, could you include the compiler error(s)?

Comment: @c1moore No errors at all. It compiles fine. However, when I run it, it just stops working,

Comment: Then why did you include #1 in your post?

Comment: @c1moore phrased it wrong, sorry. Edited the post

Comment: Tip: when output is questionable, surround _string_ output with sentinels like `<>` and  end each output with `\n`. It better exposes excessive white-space, line feed ,carriage return issues.  E.g. `printf("%.*s", line_storer, line);` --> `printf("<%.*s>\n", line_storer, line);`

Comment: For debug, suggest a different code phrase than `"The Image use to be here\n"` as that same phrase is in the `test.html` and confuses the assessment.

Comment: OT:  this: `<u><i><b>TESTING 123</u></i></b>`  is NOT valid HTML.  The control blocks must be properly nested.

Comment: what happens when the `<img>` and `</img>` are not on the same line?

Comment: @user3629249 Its just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `len = 0` before your first invocation of `getline()`.

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
```

From the manpage for `getline` ...

> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

`len` is stack-allocated - so unless you initialize it it can contain any value.

Also, you should be `free()`ing `line` before finishing.

```
free(line);
fclose(fp);
```

Lastly, you should check the return value from `fopen()`.

```
if (!fp) {
    perror("fopen");
    // Handle error and return if appropriate
}
```

#### `getline()` and Windows

I suspect the issues you are having on Windows are because Windows doesn't implement the `getline()` function. (It is not part of the C standard - it is a POSIX function.)

As an alternative you can try using `fgets()`. Example below.

**N.B.** Note that the memory for `line` is *not* being allocated dynamically in this case.

```
char line[128] = {'\0'};

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
// etc..
}
// Do NOT call free(line) at end of scope in this case!
```

Comment: Added both things, still not printing anything but now it is at least not crashing. Its not meeting the while loop condition for some reason. So it doesn't go into the while loop.

Comment: @SarahChan: In your question you state that "The code is printing _everything_". Now you state the opposite. Can you clarify?

Comment: It prints everything in linux and nothing in windows. My goal is to make it fully work in windows.

Comment: @SarahChan: It prints what seems to be the expected output for me (Linux 64-bit, gcc 6.3.0).

Comment: yea. It doesn't do it in windows (mingw gcc). What could the problem be?

Comment: @SarahChan: I don't have access to `mingw` or a Windows machine. However, are you sure the file is even being opened correctly? I ask because you are not checking the return value of `fopen()`.

Comment: the fopen works fine. The reason is because the while loop condition isn't met, so it never goes into the loop. I'm not getting any compiler errors but I edited my first post with all the libraries/#includes I am using. I have this as a separate function, so the file is already opened.

Comment: Updated my first post with how I have it as a function

Comment: @SarahChan: If you haven't done so already, I think this is a good time to use your debugger (I think `mingw` provides `gdb`). Place a breakpoint at the beginning of your `while()` loop, and - once it is reached - examine the contents of `line`, `len` and `*fp`. Then step through the program using `next` - periodically examining the afore-mentioned variables.

Comment: @SarahChan: I suspect `getline()` is not implemented on your system. I have updated my answer with a suggestion to use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: the function: `fgets()` properly handles the input buffer, so using: `sizeof( line ) -1` is not correct.  Suggest: `sizeof( line )`  Suggest reading the MAN page for `fgets()` for a full description

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `line` must be initialized to `NULL` and `len` to `0`. Without initialization, since `line` and `len` have automatic storage (aka *on the stack*), your code has undefined behavior, in your case causing early termination.
- HTML `<img>` usually have attributes such as `src=URL`

You make some assumptions, which are not necessary and actually complicate your code:
* only the first image is removed from each line.
* if the `<img>` tag and the `</img>` are on different lines, there could be a close tag appearing on the same line before an unrelated open tag. Your first test would be fooled by the situation and produce incorrect output.

Here is a corrected version with nested loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char *line, *p, *q;
    size_t len;
    bool found_tag;

    fp = fopen("test.html", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", "test.html");
        return 1;
    }

    line = NULL;
    len = 0;
    found_tag = false;
    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {
        for (p = line;;) {
            if (found_tag) {
                q = strstr(p, "</img>");
                if (q == NULL) {
                    /* skip the rest of the line */
                    break;
                }
                found_tag = false;
                p = q + strlen("</img>");
            } else {
                q = strstr(p, "<img");
                if (q == NULL) {
                    fputs(p, stdout);
                    break;
                }
                printf("%.*s%s", (int)(q - p), p,
                       "The Image used to be here\n");
                found_tag = true;
                p = q + strlen("<img");
            }
        }           
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where will I replace the the `<img>everything inside</img>` with `The Image use to be here`. Like in my output example. Also the html thing was just an example (I know its not valid html).

Comment: @SarahChan: I updated the answer to output the image placeholder `"The Image used to be here\n"`.